# Насколько прожорлив метод платформозависимой компиляции Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть строчки для исполнения платформозависимого кода

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
#if UNITY_ANDROID
```

Насколько они грузят систему? Можно ли их ставить в

```
Update(){}
```

Или как написать платформозависимый код для Update? 
Чтобы при каких то условиях запускалось именно то что нужно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это - директивы условной компиляции. Они выполняются при сборке проекта, в рантайме их не существует.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что в метод Update их можно ставить - они просто будут запускать нужный код и не будут грузить систему?

Comment: @Dmitrii при запуске их вообще нет. Они будут развёрнуты на этапе компиляции

Answer (score 3):

Как написал @Pavel Mayorov в ответе - всех этих конструкций и лишнего кода после компиляции не будет. Т.е. если вы напишите:

```
#if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
   10000 строк кода
#endif
#if UNITY_ANDROID
   10000 строк кода
#endif
```

То после компиляции у вас будут только те 10000 строк, которые относятся к платформе, под которую она проводилась.

> Или как написать платформозависимый код для Update? Чтобы при каких то условиях запускалось именно то что нужно?

Вообще, конечно, зависит от сложности проекта. Грубо говоря проекта типа Lineage 2, который Standalone еще сделать и для Андройда - я бы лично не стал делать в одном проекте сразу. Ибо можно мозг и руки все сломать.

Но для мелочи всё уходит в изготовление общего интерфейса взаимодействия и его реализацию под нужную платформу и его использование.

Пример:
Нам нужно сделать игру *Standalone* и *Android* где можно

- Кликнуть на персонажа (при клике на него он скажет "Че тыкаешь?")
- С зажатой клавишей можно двигать персонажа, он будет кричать "А-а-а, помогите, спасите, меня тошнит!"
- Можно отпустить кнопку, персонаж говорит: "Пожалуюсь в спец органы на тебя!"

В основной игре итоговый класс будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
class ControlScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public IInputController inputController;

    void Start() {
        inputController = GetInputController();        
    }


    void Update() {        
        if (inputController.IsTouchEnd())        
            Debug.Log("Пожалуюсь в спец органы на тебя!");

        if (inputController.OnTouch().Count > 0)    
            Debug.Log("Че тыкаешь?");

        if (inputController.IsCursorMoving()) 
            Debug.Log("А-а-а, помогите, спасите, меня тошнит!");            
    }

    private IInputController GetInputController() {
        IInputController controller = GetComponent<WinController>();

        #if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
           IInputController controller = GetComponent<WinController>();
        #endif
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
           IInputController controller = GetComponent<AndroidController>();
        #endif

        return controller;
    }
}
```

В нем при старте мы определяем контроллер в зависимости от платформы (`inputController = GetInputController()`), а в методе *Update* используем методы оного.

---

Ниже представлены составляющие: интерфейс IInputController и классы его реализующие.

Интерфейс для контроллера, которым будем возякать персонажа:

```
public interface IInputController {

    List<Vector3> OnTouch();

    bool IsCursorMoving();

    bool IsTouchEnd();
}
```

два класса, его реализующие (это всё условно и не является предметом для подражания):

**WinController.cs**

```
public class WinController : MonoBehaviour, IInputController {

    public List<Vector3> OnTouch() {
        List<Vector3> list = new List<Vector3>();

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            list.Add(Input.mousePosition);          

        return list;        
    }


    public bool IsCursorMoving() {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") != 0)
            return true;

        return false;
    }


    public bool IsTouchEnd() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**AndroidController.cs**

```
public class AndroidController : MonoBehaviour, IInputController {

    private const int MAX_COUNT_TOUCHES = 2;

    public List<Vector3>  OnTouch() {
        List<Vector3> list = new List<Vector3>();

        for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
            var phase = Input.GetTouch(i).phase;
            if (phase == TouchPhase.Stationary || phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {      
                list.Add(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
            }
            if (list.Count >= MAX_COUNT_TOUCHES)
                break;
        }

        return list;   
    }


    public bool IsCursorMoving() {        
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) 
            return true;

        return false;
    }


    public bool IsTouchEnd() {
        for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
            var phase = Input.GetTouch(i).phase;
            if (phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Всё.

HappyEnd.

---

**P.S.** Помимо директив препроцессора можно обратиться к статической переменной `platform` класса `Application`. Получится что-то типа такого:

```
RuntimePlatform platform = Application.platform;
if(platform == RuntimePlatform.Android || platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) {
    // do smth
}
```

ссылка на класс Application - https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Application.html
ссылка на платформы - https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/RuntimePlatform.html