# Определение устройства ввода в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, uwp

Делаю игру под UWP следовательно устройств ввода может быть 3: геймпад, клавиатура/мышь, сенсорный экран.
Следовательно нужно делать для каждого из этих типов ввода свои подсказки (нажмите LS или нажмите кнопку D), а при касании сенсорного экрана ещё и показывать виртуальный геймпад, т.е нужно чтобы на каждую нажатую кнопку на устройстве ввода происходило событие определяющее текущее устройство ввода и выполняющее действия ориентируясь на это текущее устройство ввода.
Я так понимаю для реализации этого нужно всегда иметь объект со скриптом InputController.cs на сцене и в нём опрашивать статичный класс Input? Но что там опрашивать чтобы узнать текущее устройство ввода? А может у Unity вообще есть событие или делегат, срабатывающий на ввод с устройства ввода, на которые можно подписаться в статичном классе и вообще не иметь лишнего объекта на сцене?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570610/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский проверка на платформу не подойдёт. Поскольку у любого UWP устройства могут быть сразу все варианты ввода. Например, планшеты на Windows имеют сенсорный экран и usb в который можно воткнуть и клавиатуру, и геймпад одновременно

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут http://herdo.github.io/AdaptiveTriggerLibrary/ в коллекции `User Interaction Triggers` есть 2 триггера `InputTypeTrigger` и `InteractionMode Trigger`

Там можно задавать поведение, исходя как раз из устройства ввода. Это для обычных UWP-приложений, но, возможно, это можно использовать и в вашем случае.

Comment: этот способ не позволяет узнать, что используется геймпад