# Преобразования кликов мышки в тачи

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код преобразования кликов в события тачскрина

```
void MouseMethod()
{
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        HandleTouch(touch.fingerId,touch.position, touch.phase);
    }

    // Simulate touch events from mouse events
    if (Input.touchCount == 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            HandleTouch(10, Input.mousePosition, TouchPhase.Began);
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            HandleTouch(10, Input.mousePosition, TouchPhase.Moved);
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            HandleTouch(10, Input.mousePosition, TouchPhase.Ended);
        }
    }
}

private void HandleTouch(int touchFingerId, Vector3 touchPosition, TouchPhase touchPhase)
{

    switch (touchPhase)
    {
        case TouchPhase.Began:
            Debug.Log("Беган");
            break;
        case TouchPhase.Moved:
            Debug.Log("мувд");
            break;
        case TouchPhase.Ended:
            Debug.Log("end");
            break;
    }
}
```

Работает, Debug.Log успешно выводятся при клике, удержании и отпускании кнопки.

Есть код, который работает от тачскрина

```
foreach (var th in Input.touches)
    {
        if (th.phase == TouchPhase.Began && (th.phase != TouchPhase.Moved))
        {
            TouchBegan(th);
        }
        if (th.fingerId == fId && ((th.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) || (th.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)))
        {
            TouchMovedOrStationary(th);
        }
        if (th.fingerId == fId && (th.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || th.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled))
        {
            TouchEnded();
        }
    }
```

Как их совместить? Во втором мне нужны не по отдельности фазы,fingerId и координаты, а именно само прикосновение Touch th.

Как сделать так, чтобы второй код работал от мышки?

Comment: Я вам как-то раз  одном из ответов http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570610/191482  даже писал как это делается))  Делаете общий интерфейс. Выделяете общую логику.. Создаете два контроллера, которые имплементируют методы.... в начале основного класса определяете какой именно контроллер будет задействован. И дальше обращаетесь непосредственно к его методам.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я правильно вас понял, что вы предлагаете при помощи директив препроцессора просто создать два разных класса и использовать их на разных платформах? Тач на андроиде, мышку на пк?
Вопрос то тут немного в другом - как подсунуть контроллёру тачскрина мышечные координаты и преобразовать в фазы тача нажатие кнопок. Чтобы одновременно работала и мышка и тач. 
А то у нас есть фаза, есть fingerId, есть координаты. Как это подставить в формулу для тачскрина?

Comment: А что за устройство или игра, где нужно одновременно и мышка и тач? Что-то я просто не встречал подобных игр.